# select xml tag and run the .exe

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

Currently i am running this in my UI. This happens during a button event:

```
wco "C:\folder1\"
```

In the above code, i am executing wco.exe followed by the folder name.

so my question is, is it possible to do this instead:

1. click on button
2. open an xml file
3. get the code from an xml element
4. run the code

so my xml file would look something like this:

```
<main>
   <versions>
      <version1>wco "C:\folder1\"</version1>
   </versions>
</main>
```

if so how do i go about doing this?

EDIT 1:

This is how i run my code at the moment:

```
private void tab1nextButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

                string antText = "-f -R \"C:\\folder1\"";
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("wco", antText);
        }
```

where -f and -R are just some parameters

Comment: So the user clicks the button - are you saying the code then opens an xml file?  Or the user selects one?  Either way it's possible

Comment: so i am saying click button event opens up the xml file and go to <version 1>, get the command "wco "c:\folder1\" and run it

Comment: @Fredrik Mork i dont understand your question

Comment: @jeremychan: In your question you write *"Currently i am running this in my UI."* using `wco "C:\folder1\"` as an example. I doubt you simply have a code line saying only that (that would hardly compile), so my question is *"how to you run it right now?"*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Linq to Xml like this (add your error handling, and GUI):

```
    var x = XElement.Load(@"c:\temp\config.xml");
    var xElement = x.Element("versions").Element("version1");
    var p = new Process
    {
        StartInfo =
            new ProcessStartInfo(xElement.Attribute("exe").Value,
                                 xElement.Attribute("arguments").Value)
    };
    p.Start();
```

with a slightly modified config to help with parsing:

```
<main>
  <versions>
    <version1 exe="wco" arguments="C:\folder1\" />
  </versions>
</main>
```

Comment: hi if i want to have -f -R in my parameter as shown in my edit, how do i add them?

Comment: @jeremychan <version1 exe="wco" arguments='-f -R "C:\folder1\"' />